# Dell Chromebook (Candy 2015) - No Sound and Touchpad

Tags: touchpad, hardware, speakers

Basically like the title says!:

I've installed Ubuntu Trusty on my Dell Chromebook (Candy-2015 edition) but the sound and the touchpad are not working,

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

https://plus.google.com/+JamesFuBEEFCAKE/posts/Tf4Pc5Z8reH

This worked for me for the sound. It's still not working with the internal speakers, but it works out of the jack 1/8 and HDMI.

My touchpad worked out of the box, but it stopped working a couple of days ago. I'm still looking for a fix.